# Analyze SCSS with SonarQube on TeamCity

Tags: sass, sonarqube, teamcity, sonar-runner, scss-lint

I am using [SONAR-CSS-PLUGIN](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin) to check all `SCSS` file in my repository.

As it comes with default set of 100+ rules, at this moment am not willing to apply all rules in one go as as there is legacy code too and it's reporting many errors.

I would like to incremental by applying a set of rules (lets say 10) everyweek.

I am using `TeamCity` as build tool.

Here is my `TeamCity` configuration.

```
-Dsonar.language=scss
-Dsonar.inclusions=Src/**/*.scss
-Dsonar.css.configPath= wanna give path to .stylelintrc or custom set of rules
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
%sonar.github.pullRequest%
%sonar.github.repository%
```

I can not find any documentaion showing how to configure above plugin in `TeamCity`.

Is this `-Dsonar.css.configPath` right property??

No matter what path I provide  `-Dsonar.css.configPath= SomePath` It always applies all the rules bydefault.

I would like to apply only some rules for time being.

Comment: Please, read [Fixing the Water Leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak) before going further.

Comment: @JeroenHeier yeah I am aware about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For people who may need it in future)

Well, I asked question on their git-hub repository.

Good to know they are responsive.

**And the creator says its not possible to point any `.stylelintrc` at this moment.**

Also to apply a set of rules one need to create new `Quality Profile` and set that as default for respective repository in sonar web interface.

Note: Above option is available only for Administrator access.

See detailed thread [HERE](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/issues/81)